# How to handle the case if item is undefined?

Tags: javascript

In an `array of objects` I am trying to create a new property based on another `array of numbers`.
The problem is that the `number of array` has one less element, therefore it gets `undefined` in the last index of `array of objects`.
How to handle that case, if the new created property is `undefined`? See the code example below

```js
const sortArr = [3, 2, 1];

const items= [
  {
    a: 1,
  },
  {
    a: 2,
  },
  {
    a: 3,
  },
  {
    a: 4,
  },
];

const res =
items.map((item, idx) => ({
    ...item,
      sortItem:sortArr[idx]
  }));
  
  console.log(res)
```

Comment: *How to handle that case?* That depends on you, what do you'd expect as fallback behaviour?

Comment: I'd expect smth like, if it's the last in the array or doesn't exist, then show nothing/empty string

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I expect to have empty string/0  instead of undefined

Comment: `sortItem: sortArr[idx] ?? 'fallback value'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it's the last in the array then show nothing/empty string

To use an empty string as fallback if `sortArr[inx]` does not exist, use the [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator:

```js
sortItem: sortArr[idx] ?? ''
```

---

```js
const sortArr = [3, 2, 1];
const items= [{a: 1, }, {a: 2, }, {a: 3, }, {a: 4, }, ];

const res = items.map((item, idx) => (
    {
        ...item,
        sortItem: sortArr[idx] ?? ''
    }
));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: As an alternative, if `sortArr[idx]` might contain falsy values like `0`, you could replace [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) with [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) in order to _only_ replace with an empty string (`''`) in the case that `sortArr[idx]` is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderNied, thats probably a better way to see this.

Comment: @0stone0 thanks for answer. Is it also possible not to show anything, just an empty space, rather than showing empty string?

Comment: Not sure what you'd mean by 'nothing' There is no 'nothing' in javascript. You can replace the `''` with anything you'd like: `0`, `NULL`, etc...

Comment: You are right,  it was really a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

You can set sortItem based on whether idx is less than sortArr.length

`sortItem: idx < sortArr.length ? sortArr[idx] : "no element at that position"`